# Is there a standard library solution to this Haskell problem?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, standard-library

I want to use Data.List.groupBy to group a list of tuples based on the equality of the `snd` element.
I could do this:

```
groupBy (\l r -> snd l == snd r) listOfTuples
```

But it strikes me as too much boilerplate in the comparison function -- especially because it could get a lot more messy if I were doing a more complicated comparison.  I would like to do something like:

```
groupBy (comparing snd) listOfTuples
```

but the type signature of comparing is `comparing :: (Ord a) => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering`, so it doesn't compile in this example.
I could also do:

```
groupBy (\l r -> (comparing snd l r) == EQ) listOfTuples
```

But this is no better than the first try.  Is there a standard-library solution to this problem, before I roll-my-own?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
groupBy ((==) `on` snd) listOfTuples
```

I think there used to be `equating = on (==)` in the standard libraries, though I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: What package does `on` come from?

Comment: @Matt: Data.Function (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v:on) in general you can search for functions on hoogle: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=on

Comment: I love the `on` operator.  It's almost plain english "group by equality on the second members, for a list of tuples".

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
groupBy ((==EQ) . comparing snd) listOfTuples
```

Comment: Hmm, I always think . is magical. But alas it isn't. I think there's a lift function that maybe does something similar. `lift :: (a->b) -> (c->d->b) -> c -> d`. Hoogle gives me `on` as @Daniel Wagner suggested.

Comment: You can write it as `groupBy (((== EQ).) . comparing snd) listOfTuples`. Note the partially applied function composition.